# Web Power Query No Longer Working for Yahoo Finance

Tags: excel, powerquery

I previously had a Web Power Query for Yahoo Finance which would pull in stock data (specifically dividend information) which looked like this

```
= (Ticker as text) as table=>

let

Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&Ticker&"/key-statistics?p="&Ticker)),

Data3 = Source{3}[Data],

#"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(Data3)

in

#"Demoted Headers"
```

This used to work and would give me results such as this

[image]

However, over the last few weeks or so, when running this query, I get the following results

[image]

This is not an error I was getting when I first implemented the code and was previously running it.

How do I resolve this issue?
(have previously asked this on r/Excel but the only response I got was "well it works for me")

Comment: What do you get if you call the URL manually? You might be firewalled, rate limited or interfered with by a proxy changing the response. You can consider evaluating `Source` independently to see what's in it, since this query blindly accesses `Source{3}`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert If I call the URL with a ticker such as [AAPL in my browser](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL), it loads completely fine. In the web preview on Power Query, it shows the loaded website with the massive Cookie Consent popup in the middle

Comment: Whenever I've seen this error it was the result of a remote API flaking out and giving an incomplete response (or timing out) in response to me overloading it. Not saying that's what's going on here, but it seems possible if you're retrieving enough individual tickers this way.

Comment: I don't think it is that, given I'm also getting the errored response when attempting it with just a single ticker

Comment: extend your question to show the code for how you are calling the function, and using what input table

Comment: @horseyride In this example of the code, the function is simply being called as is, in that in the power query window, I'm adding a ticker to a text box and it's adding it in to where ticker is called as a variable